# perl "or" to go through a list

Tags: perl, file-handling

I have written a small script that goes looking for a file with a certain ID-number in three different folders. My first attempt to do this was this:

```
open my $fh, "<", "dir1/file.o$ARGV[0]"
or open my $fh, "<", "dir2/file.o$ARGV[0]"
or open my $fh, "<", "dir3/file.o$ARGV[0]"
     or die "Couldn't open `file.o$ARGV[0]' for reading: $!";
```

This resulted in an empty file handle for files in dir2, which I used for testing, and I have now written an elaborate if(...) else if (...) structure to do what I want. But I still don't understand why my first approach didn't work, so I'm hoping for some insights.

My expectation was that it would try to open the first file, if that failed, look at what comes after the or, try to open that file and so on. Where am I going wrong?

Bonus question: Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: This compiles just fine. It raises a warning that you have `$fh` declared multiple times ( `"my" variable $fh masks earlier declaration in same statement` ) but that doesn't stop it compiling.

Comment: Oh, right, it did compile, but the filehandle was empty afterwards (at least if the file was in the first two directories, didn't test the third). Anyway it didn't do what I wanted it to do. And I forgot to enable warnings, so I asked this rather stupid question...

Comment: I wouldn't call it a stupid question, but I wouldn't be so generous about your description of the problem as *"This didn't work"*!

Comment: I didn't really remember what exactly happened, but know I checked again and edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Is there an elegant way to do this?"*

The warning is because of multiple declarations of `$fh`, as has already been explained, but I would prefer to see the file selected separately, because

- There may be more than one file with the desired ID
- If the file is in `dir1` or `dir2` but the `open` fails for some other reason, your program will go on to try `dir3` and wrongly report `No such file or directory`

I suggest something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($id) = @ARGV;

my $filename = do {
    my @files = grep -f, map "$_/file.o$id", qw/ dir1 dir2 dir3 /;
    die @files . " matching files found" unless @files == 1;
    $files[0];
};

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Couldn't open "$filename" for reading: $!};
```

Comment: In this case the ID comes out of a job handling system, so they're all unique, but a good point in general. Also thanks for pointing out the problem with the potentially wrong error report.

Answer (score 4):

You're duplicating the declaration of `$fh`.  Move that out:

```
my $fh;

   open $fh, '<', 'test1'
or open $fh, '<', 'test2'
or open $fh, '<', 'test3'
or die "Can't open whatever: $!";
```

Comment: Sometimes it's just so obvious... I somehow thought that because only one of the "open"s would take effect that was ok. Anyway, mystery solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you enable warnings it will tell you `"my" variable $fh masks earlier declaration in same statement`

As an alternative, you can use foreach to loop over files,

```
my @files = map "dir$_/file.o$ARGV[0]", 1 ..3;

my $fh;
for (@files) {
  open($fh, "<", $_) and last;
  undef $fh;
}
$fh or die $!;
```

Comment: Upvoted because it reminded me that map can be used without of block.